# Segmentation fault in semaphores and synchronization

Tags: c, synchronization, segmentation-fault, semaphore

Sometimes this program errors with a segmentation fault. What is a segmentation fault? Why is it happening? And how do I fix it?

I am expecting the output as:

```
I am consumer
I am producer 
I am consumer
I am producer
(etc.)
```

However, this is not the case. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

sem_t* mutex;
sem_t* null;

main()
{
 int temp;
 int pid;
 pid = fork();

 sem_unlink("/mutex");
 sem_unlink("/null");

 null = (sem_t*)sem_open("/null",O_CREAT,S_IWUSR|S_IWGRP|S_IWOTH,0);
 mutex =(sem_t*)sem_open("/mutex",O_CREAT,S_IWUSR|S_IWGRP|S_IWOTH,1);


 if (pid != 0)
 while(1)
 {
   sem_post(null);
   sem_wait(mutex);
   printf("\nIam In Producer\n");
   scanf("%d",&temp); // just  for my verification that where i am during execution
   sem_post(mutex);
   sem_wait(null);
 }

 else
 while(1)
 {
   sem_post(null);
   sem_wait(mutex);
   printf("\nIam In consumer\n");
   scanf("%d",&temp); // just for my verification that where i am during execution
   sem_post(mutex);
   sem_wait(null);
 }

}
```

---

Comment: First, change the name of the "null" semaphore to something else.  You might also consider checking to see if the sem_open calls are succeeding.

Comment: You should be including `<unistd.h>` for `fork()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to move the `sem_unlink()` and `sem_open()` calls to *before* you call `fork()`.  You're probably unlinking things you don't want to.

Explanation - you call `fork()`, now you have two processes running.  Let's say the parent gets through the `sem_unlink()` and `sem_open()` calls before the child gets any processor time.  Now the child starts running, and immediately unlinks the parent's semaphores!

Comment: If i moved sem_open before fork() how forked process can share it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you `sem_open()` both in the child and the parent, but the first call creates the semaphore with wrong permissions, so the second `sem_open()` fails because access is denied to the semaphore.  You don't check whether the call succeeds, so the semaphore will be invalid, that's why you get the segfault when you try to use it.  Try to move `fork()` after the semaphores are created, or change the semaphore permissions.  And don't forget to check the result of any call that might fail :)

Comment: i need more explanations. What is the wrong permissions there.

Comment: `S_IWUSR|S_IWGRP|S_IWOTH` means it's only *writable* by user/group/other, so the other process can't open it.  Change it to `S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO` and that should solve the problem.